# Passing value to directive and change css properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I'm trying to get my head around these directives.

Basic Problem: 
I have a property in my scope called arrow which holds the angle the image (arrow) should be turned in by css (transform:rotate). I have build a directive which should do that job:

HTML:

```
<div class="weather-div">
  <img ng-src="../img/icons/wetter/wind-arrows/direction.png" 
       arrowdirection="{{ menu.weather.arrow }}">
</div>
```

Directive:

```
    AppDirectives.directive("arrowdirection", [function(){

      return {
      template: '',
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {  },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // get the angle from the parent scope  
            var angle = scope.arrow;

            // get the image to turn () 
            var element = angular.element(document).find('#theimagetofindfromsameobjectdirectiveisin');

            // turn img
            element.css({
                 '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                 '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                 '-o-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
            });




      }
    };

}]);
```

1: How do I access the parent scope value menu.weather.arrow in the directive or pass the value into the directive and access it there?
2: How do I get the image element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate writing blind directives(so much room for error when you can't test). If you produce a fiddle/plnkr I can update.

Key take aways:

1. You dont need to use `ng-src`unless you are binding to something that will change.
2. `scope: {}` isolates you from the parent controller.  You need to use the scope attribute to link arrow-direction to arrow on scope  (`arrow='=arrowDirection`).  That sets up a two way data binding to the value you set when calling the directives.
3. When using scope in directives if you want camel case you put a `-` between words.
4. `arrow` will not be set with the directive links so you need to setup a watch.
5. angular gives you access to the `element` the directive is attached to so you dont need to query for it.
6. Take more time asking your question, your more likely to get a response if you A. format your code, B. create a simple example with a fiddle/plnkr

---

```
<div class="weather-div">
    <img src="../img/icons/wetter/wind-arrows/direction.png" 
         arrow-direction=" menu.weather.arrow">
</div>
```

---

```
//Javascript
AppDirectives.directive("arrowdirection", [function(){
  return {
  template: '',
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
      arrow :'=arrowDirection'
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // get the angle from the parent scope  
        var angle = scope.arrow;
        scope.$watch('arrow', function(){
          // get the image to turn () 
          // element is the img 
          element.css({
             '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
             '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
             '-o-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
             '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
          });
        });

    }
  };
}]);
```